# Passing several fields as parameters to methods in other class, or pass `this` and make the fields public

Tags: c#, field, parameter-passing, cancellation

I think I have missed out on a basic concept in object oriented programming.

Let's say several methods in class B want to access several fields that are declared in class A. Should I pass all the fields as parameters to the methods, starting from class A and down the potentially long call tree in class B? `classBInstance.StartOfLongCallTree(p1, p2, p3)`

Or, should I make the fields public and pass `this` to the methods. That way I only have to pass one parameter: `classBInstance.StartOfLongCallTree(this)`.

Or, should I make the fields / properties static and access them without passing any parameters? This only applies in the case that the fields do not need to vary across instances obviously. `classBInstance.StartOfLongCallTree()`. `ClassA.p1` etc., to access the static fields.

An example is CancellationToken to cancel loops in threads. I have a long call tree in my program that runs across two classes/threads. I can either pass the token down the call tree, or I can make a public static property of it, to avoid having to pass it at all. Which one should I go for?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You don't pass classes, you pass objects which are instances of the class

Comment: You can make use of an interface for all the public members and pass `this` in. I would not recommend making methods/members in `class B` static unless you have a good reason for it. Can you please add some sample code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Andrew I cannot find where I said I was passing a class. I will fix it if I had that typo. I am passing `this`, which is an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the application, making field or methods as **statis** maybe be very **danger** because they are the same in every instance of their owner class, but most of times when more than one **Attribute** of let say class **A** is required in class let say **B** then class **B** will holds an instance of class **A** instead of it's attributes and will use that instance to access the fields so it's enough to just pass **this** inside **A** to **B**